# Is there an auto update for the GoG Galaxy Client?

Tags: gog, gog-galaxy

How does the GoG Galaxy Client Update? I can't find any option to run an update manually but it also does not seem to update itself automatically.

How do I update the bloody thing?

Comment: I don't think the client can update itself yet, since games auto update also isn't in the beta either

Comment: @PrivatePansy How would you update it then? Or know that there is a new version? There is no entry in my library anymore since the OB started and the client / website do not display any version numbers.

Comment: I've looked at it, and it seems the only place where version numbers can be found is on the `GalaxyClient.exe` file itself, and on the file name of the installer. So far the version installed is the same as the version on their website, and the file has not changed since I installed it

Comment: The settings window claims that auto update is coming soon, but it seemed to already be there for games. The GoG Galaxy Client was able to find three out of my many already installed games, and all three of them automatically updated shortly after I first started the client. This leads me to the conclusion that either the information in the settings panel is wrong or it refers to the client itself (which would thus not update itself.).

Comment: @Nick Yes, games work but the question was specifically about the self update of the client.

Comment: Today my client updated itself prior to starting, so I can confirm the client is already capable of updating itself. Sort of wish there's a changelog or release notes for it somewhere though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GoG team have marked the ["Auto update galaxy client"](http://www.gog.com/wishlist/galaxy/auto_update_galaxy_client) wish as completed. The wish-list can be found at [here](http://www.gog.com/wishlist/galaxy). This strongly implies that it does indeed have the ability to auto update itself.

Comment: The staff comment says "Client auto-update is already in since the very beginning", so the feature should be in the current client as well